# How do I find out the anchor in the URI in Pyramid?

Tags: python, uri, anchor, pyramid

Simply put, in Pyramid, when someone requests a page e.g.:

```
/foo/#bar
```

How do I find out what the anchor is? In this case, it would be `bar`. This seems like it should be trivial, but I'm not sure how to retrieve this information in Pyramid.

`request.current_route_path()`, `request.url` and `request.path` would only return `/foo/` in this scenario.

(Is Pyramid actually left completely unaware of this? Maybe servers simply never receive this information and I've never realised that 'til now)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fragment is never sent to the server by the client; you will need to use JavaScript to process it on the client side.